# Thymeleaf internationalization (i18n) and html tags

Tags: spring-mvc, internationalization, thymeleaf

I have html code which has to be generated in different languages.

```
Click <a href="https://here">here</a> 
Kliknij <a href="https://here">tutaj</a>
```

How to handle this simple example with i18n and Thymeleaf assuming that `url` is a user input?

I try:

```
messages.click_here = Click <a href="{0}">here</a>
```

and then in thymeleaf:

```
<span th:text="#{messages.click_here(${url})}"></span>
```

but then my code is not interpreted as HTML

so I can use `utext`

```
<span th:utext="#{messages.click_here(${url})}"></span>
```

But now my application is exposed to code injection. Someone could pass malicious parameter through `${url}`, close the tag and generate js. `utext` can do anything.

What is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be better divided `Click <a href="https://here">here</a>` into 2 message string?

```
message.click=Click
message.here=here

<sapn th:text="#{message.click}"/> <a th:href="@{/here}" th:text="#{message.here}"></a>
```

Comment: For this simple example it works. But there may be a case where order of words in the sentence is important (different language family) and translation is "here click".